# Pass a hidden field value to javascript (href)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using javascript to do href. The code as below

```
 <script>
    window.onunload = refreshParent;
    function refreshParent() {
        var SAPno = document.getElementById('HiddenNo');
        window.opener.location.href="Inventory.aspx?" + "SAPNo="+ SAPno +;
    }
</script>
```

my hidden field code as below

```
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenNo" runat="server" />
```

may I know how to use the value in hiddenfield and pass to Inventory.aspx? and anyone know how to retrieve the value?

Thanks!

Comment: Hidden fields can be present in any form submission and their value at the time the form is submitted will be included in the form data that is sent to the server just like any other value in the form.  Server-side, you retrieve them the same way you retrieve any other form.  Client-side, you give them a value just like any other form field has a value.  The only difference is that they aren't visible to the end-user.  They are regular form fields that are simply not displayed.

Comment: Note: *Browsers equipped with pop-up window blockers will ignore all window.open() method calls in onunload event handler functions.* See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script> 
   window.onunload = refreshParent; 
   function refreshParent() { 
     var SAPno = document.getElementById('HiddenNo').value;   
     window.opener.location.href="Inventory.aspx?" + "SAPNo="+ SAPno
   } 
</script>
```

If you want to use JQuery then

```
$('HiddenNo').val()
```